# Is it OK to use hyperopic to refer to farsightedness metaphorically?

Tags: word-usage

I have seen the word myopic used metaphorically to refer to a person who is very short-sighted (can't anticipate the consequences of their actions). Of course myopic is also used in the medical sense to refer to a person who is literally short-sighted.

Is hyperopic also commonly used this way to refer to a person who has exceptional planning abilities and can anticipate consequences easily? Are there examples of it being used this way? Dictionaries define it in the medical sense only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general few would use a negative medical condition to describe a positive trait.

This would be the equivalent of saying that some has [**hypertrophic cardiomyopathy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertrophic_cardiomyopathy) when you mean they have a *big heart*.

[***Foresightedness (n.)***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foresight) is a far more positive way to say this than [**farsightedness (n.)**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/farsighted).  While farsightedness is acceptable, it still carries an initial "recoil" as a negative before it gets reinterpreted as potentially positive.

> His foresightedness was legendary.
>   He possessed great foresight.
>   He was foresighted.

Comment: "Foresightedness" is an abomination.  The trait is "foresight"; one who has foresight is "foresighted"; it's ridiculous to add *-ness* to get back to where you started.  In contrast, "farsight" is not a common noun; "farsightedness" actually makes sense.  Ngrams (not an authority, I know) seem to agree with me: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foresightedness%2C+farsightedness&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforesightedness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfarsightedness%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @MT_Head Argue with the fine folks at Dictionary.com.  Foresightedness is the noun.  Why not argue with weakness, ugliness, and just about any other usage of the suffix.

Comment: You've definitely missed my point... Where is the base noun in "weakness"?

Comment: @MT_Head I understood your point.  I just disagree.  I think calling it an abomination is ... overreacting.  Adding -ness in this case changes it to a noun that describes the characteristic instead of just the item you possess.

Comment: @MT_Head Read my revision and you will see the interplay of the forms.

Comment: @DavidM Would it be worthwhile to add that _farsightedness_ implies a defect in near vision, and not merely good distance vision?  This implicit visual restriction undermines the benefit.  Though, I agree that to use a negative condition to describe a positive trait produces some "recoil."

Comment: @Mike I would have said that, but I looked at the definition and it *is* included. I don't like it either, but apparently people use it.

Comment: According to the good people of Etymonline (as cited by Dictionary.com), "farsighted" was first used - in a positive sense - in the 1640s, while the "hyperopia" sense didn't appear until 1878.  History and literary tradition are on the side of "farsighted" being a *good* thing.

Comment: @DavidM - "Foresightedness" seems ridiculous to me for the same reason that "beautifulness" would.  First we have a quality **x**; we add a suffix to turn it into an adjective meaning "possessing quality x"; then we add a suffix to mean "the quality of possessing quality x".  I don't dispute that it's in the dictionary; given time, a lot of tripe ends up in the dictionary - see [irregardless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregardless).  I **do** dispute that it ought to be recommended.

Comment: I would have had no objection at all if you'd just recommended "foresight", by the way.

Comment: @MT_Head I don't disagree with your hatred of words like irregardless. Nor do I like that literally gets a dictionary entry for the meaning figuratively. But, I'm not able to edit the language. And if I'm being honest … my preference for the long form of the verb stems from little more than the mellifluous nature of the sound of the word … ;-)

Comment: In a world where reading is less common than today, farsightedness is a much more positive trait than a negative one. Being able to see well at long distances has uses, that others appreciate.

Comment: @DavidM - If mellifluousness is the goal, how about "foresightednessfullnessishness"?  I believe that would be the quality of having the quality of having the quality of foresight...

Comment: @MT_Head I will immediately add it to my lexicon.

Comment: Never use two syllables where eight will do!

Comment: @MT_Head I think you've gathered by now that I would use either of them without regret. I agree that it's origin is perhaps nebulous, but I think like many such accidental constructs it exists because of its tonal similarity to more familiar terms.  Had you not called it an abomination in the first place, I likely would have changed it … ;-)

Comment: I run into constructions of this kind *all the time* in technical writing and business mumbo-jumbo, and they raise my hackles every time.  This particular instance happens to be a few hundred years old, but...

Comment: ... and by the way - I believe a person with a big heart simply has  [cardiomegaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiomegaly), in keeping with my theme of syllabic reduction...  =D

Comment: @MT_Head Here you shall not challenge me!   ;-). Cardiomegaly *is* enlargement of the heart. But the subtype hypertrophic cardiomyopathy is the proliferation of tissue, compared to dilated cardiomyopathy which is a mere stretching out of the muscle … So, I prefer hypertrophic cardiomyopathy in the same way I prefer a larger pair of socks to an old stretched out pair … (Source:  4 years of Med School, 4 Years of Residency, 9 years of practice.)

Comment: How 'bout we split the difference: your average big-hearted individual has hypertrophic cardiomyopathy, while the Grinch - whose heart grew three sizes that day - has dilated cardiomyopathy... but they both have cardiomegaly.  (Your biller will advise you that all three of these terms need further specificity to ensure payment, however.  But at least, as of today, you won't have to convert to ICD-10 until next year.  Thank Heaven for small mercies.)

Comment: @MT_Head Yes, ICD-10 would require us to explain that it was hypertrophic cardiomyopathy in the library with the candlestick . . . or something like that.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen "hyperopic" used this way, but its usual layman's equivalent **[farsighted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/farsighted)** is quite commonly used in this sense.